# Shopify GrahpQL API - How Do I Grab 9,000 inventory_item_ids for InventoryActivate Mutation?

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

Trying to set the `available` inventory for a large amount of products within multiple locations.

The problem I am running into is there is just so many products that I need to find their `inventory_item_id` in order to utilize the `inventoryActivate` mutation.

How can I grab a list of ALL of my 9,000 products `inventory_item_id` without going one-by-one?

Use Case:

- 10 Locations used in Shopify
- 9,000 Products in Shopify
- ERP creates and holds the physical inventory of each
- Need to update the Inventory of each Product at its respective location every hour or so

I am looking at the [docs found here](https://shopify.dev/api/examples/product-inventory#set-inventory-levels-to-a-certain-amount).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that we can utilize the `bulkOperationRunQuery` [following the docs here](https://shopify.dev/api/usage/bulk-operations/queries#bulk-query-overview).

1. I first ran the following to create the bulk operation with sku and inventoryItem:

```html
mutation {
  bulkOperationRunQuery(
   query: """
    {
      products {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            variants(first: 5)
        {
          edges {
            node {
                id
              sku
              inventoryItem {
                id  #this is the inventory_item_id
              }
            }
          }
        }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    """
  ) {
    bulkOperation {
      id
      status
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

2. After completed I then grabbed the Url returned from the Bulk Operation:

```html
query {
  node(id: "gid://shopify/BulkOperation/123456789") {
    ... on BulkOperation {
      url
      partialDataUrl
    }
  }
}
```

3. When we go to the URL we get a downloadable .jsonl file.  I parsed it with PHP to grab only the `sku` and `InventoryItem` id:

```html
print '<table>';
$file = @fopen("bulk.json", "r");
while (!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
    $obj = json_decode($line);
    $sku = $obj->sku;
    $inv_id = $obj->inventoryItem->id;
    $inv_id = str_replace("gid://shopify/InventoryItem/", "", $inv_id);
    if($inv_id != ''){
    print "<tr>
    <td>$sku</td>";
    print "<td>$inv_id</td>
    </tr>";
    }
}
print '</table>';
```

This provided me with all 9,000 Products Inventory Item IDs to be used on any subsequent Inventory Updates we need to call with GraphQL.

Comment: Wow. You followed my instructions and found Nirvana. So nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can export inventory in bulk and get your needed inventory item IDs, current quantities and location. Using that file (JSON) you can then loop through those and activate your inventory items.